# SQL Stored Procedure is Taking Hours to Execute from Application but not from SSMS (Azure SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have a stored procedure which takes over an hour to execute on an Azure SQL server when called from ExecuteNonQuery in .NET code. It takes just 6.5 minutes when the stored procedure's code is executed through SSMS.

Below is a snippet of the SQL code it contains (tables renamed for privacy):

```
-- Create temp Product Aggregation table.
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS [dbo].[IX_tmpProductAggregation_PID];

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProductAggregation') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [#ProductAggregation];
CREATE  TABLE [#ProductAggregation](
PID decimal(12,0) NOT NULL,
ISBN13 varchar(13) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
CompetitorAggregationId varchar(32) NULL,
EBookWorkId int NULL,
ProductAggregationId varchar(32) NULL);

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tmpProductAggregation_PID] ON [#ProductAggregation](
    PID ASC
);

-- Get Book Items to create aggregation.
INSERT  INTO [#ProductAggregation] (PID, ISBN13)
SELECT  C.PID, C.ISBN13
FROM    dbo.CompetitorAggregation AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN    dbo.BookProducts AS C WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.ISBN13 = C.ISBN13
UNION
SELECT  B.PID, C.ISBN13
FROM    dbo.EBookWorks AS B WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN    dbo.BookProducts AS C WITH (NOLOCK) ON B.PID = C.PID
```

Table BookProducts has just over 10 million rows and the result set of that union is 8 million rows. The statement takes 6.5 minutes to execute in SSMS.

We have indices on all tables. ISBN13 is a primary key (clustered) and PID is a non-clustered index.

Compile time is maximum 4.9 seconds for that statement, and it doesn't look like it could be parameter sniffing. There are no hardcoded values or parameters in this stored procedure.

I tried setting ARITHABORT to OFF and ON in SSMS, it makes no difference.

What could be causing the extremely long duration on ExecuteNonQuery?

Is the server corrupted somehow? What can be done on the SQL Server to improve the performance?

Comment: Creating statistics could cause such a delay; one execution plan may not trigger the creation of such statistics while another does. See [this article](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) for an extensive treatment of the different reasons why execution plans can be different between an application and SSMS (not tailored to Azure SQL specifically, but execution plan changes due to different settings applies to all versions of SQL Server).

Comment: I did look at that article, thanks. That's where I got the idea to look at query plans. Also, my stored procedure has no parameters, so I don't think it's parameter sniffing.

Comment: Have you got Asynchronous Statistics Updates ON? Have you tried clearing the plan cache (`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`)? **And why are you using `NOLOCK`? [see here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)?** Have you considered rewriting the query into a single `BookProducts` references with two left joins?

Comment: 6.5 minutes is good? This alone seems awful, so an hour I can't even. In addition to other suggestions you can try UNION ALL instead of UNION but we can't really help unless you can show us the execution plans that were generated in each case.

Comment: I am going to try `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`. The thing is, this stored procedure used to take 10-15 min until about yesterday when there was a minor change deployed (not even related to this SQL statement). This statement has been unchanged for months or maybe even a year.

Comment: @Charlieface I tried two left joins. It makes it about 3X slower. Also, NOLOCK is there because we don't want to lock the tables for minutes while the stored proc is running. Those tables can get updated pretty frequently. What I have considered is if somehow I can use the date stamps from the tables to narrow down the results to only what has changed, but I don't think that is feasible either.

Comment: Is it possible to do a trace on an Azure SQL server? The only thing I have been able to find out is the compile time, and I have the query plans and did a diff between them, there is no difference between the one that runs fast and the one that runs slow, other than the compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the following query to get the handle to the bad query plan:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT
        qs.[sql_handle], qs.plan_handle,
        txs = qs.statement_start_offset, 
        txe = qs.statement_end_offset,
        [size] = cp.size_in_bytes, 
        [uses] = SUM(cp.usecounts), 
        [last] = MAX(qs.last_execution_time)
    FROM 
        sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    INNER JOIN 
        sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp 
        ON qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
    GROUP BY 
        qs.[sql_handle], qs.plan_handle, cp.size_in_bytes,
        qs.statement_start_offset, qs.statement_end_offset
) 
SELECT 
    x.plan_handle, 
    size, uses, [last],
    [statement] = COALESCE(NULLIF(
        SUBSTRING(t.[text], x.txs/2, 
          CASE WHEN x.txe = -1 THEN 0 ELSE (x.txe - x.txs)/2 END
          ), ''), t.[text]) 
FROM x 
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(x.[sql_handle]) AS t
WHERE (t.text LIKE '%UNION%' AND t.text LIKE '%CompetitorAggregation%');
```

Then, an admin on the database server ran the following:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (<plan_handle from above query>)

EXEC sp_recompile [<name of the stored procedure>]
```

After these queries were executed, we are down to a 15 minute run time which is quite acceptable for us, as this process does not run very often (every 6 hours).

Update: The problem is back, after only a few days. We need a more permanent solution.

Update (2): I inspected the query plan of the stored procedure using the following query:

```
SELECT q.last_execution_time, p.is_parallel_plan, t.query_sql_text, p.query_plan FROM
sys.query_store_query q
join sys.query_store_plan p on q.query_id = p.query_id
join sys.query_store_query_text t on q.query_text_id = t.query_text_id
WHERE q.object_id = object_id('dbo.ProductAggregation_Update')
```

I found something interesting. The insert into the non-clustered index for the temp table has a very high cost. So I reworked the temp table to the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ProductAggregation') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [#ProductAggregation];
CREATE  TABLE [#ProductAggregation](
PID decimal(12,0) NOT NULL,
ISBN13 varchar(13) NOT NULL,
CompetitorAggregationId varchar(32) NULL,
EBookWorkId int NULL,
ProductAggregationId varchar(32) NULL

PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PID, ISBN13)
);
```

Hopefully this will speed it up. There was significant subtree cost (around 4000) associated with inserting into the non-clustered index, IX_tmpProductAggregation_PID.

Update (3): After making the above optimization, our execution time is down to 8 minutes.

Update (4): Even with above optimization, we're getting run times sometimes up to 1 hour.

So I added a left join with the target table and a comparison of DateChanged between source (CompetitorAggregation) and target (ProductAggregation), to narrow down the data set to only the records that were changed since last run. This has reduced run time down to 1.5 minutes. We'll have to test to see if we get spikes to 1 hour again or other regressions.

Update (5): I have found a way to get rid of the UNION also. I have separated it into two insert statements and changed the primary key like so:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PID, ISBN13) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
```

This gets rid of the DISTINCT Sort operation in the query plan.

Comment: If there's a good plan and a bad plan, Query Store should be capable of picking/pinning the good plan.

Answer (score 1):

1. Avoid using UNION in your insert query.
2. Create index on the four tables if they do not already have them
3. Use two insert queries instead of one.
   Insert into (temp table) SELECT data from first query
   Insert into (temp table) SELECT data from second query where not exists

Should the two queries in the union statement join on isbn number?  The first one joins on isbn number and the second one on PID.  I'm assuming your query is correct.